# Can Jupyter Notebook accept username and passwords to start a session?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible that when a user goes to our notebook server that he/she can login using their username and password defined in /etc/passwd (which in turn uses our institution's yp) and has all the permissions of that user? Perhaps starting a new session in the user's home directory?

Comment: are you looking for https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub?

Answer (score 2):

You should use jupyterhub for this. There you can choose between several authencation-mechanism like PAM or LDAP. You may even want to write your own.

Check https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for more info